# Show output of a directly called python script in the calling shell?

Tags: python, windows

Is there a way to get the python output in the shell from where i call the script?
(Calling with the script name only, eg. `PS>myscript.py`)

More generally phrased: Is there a way to make `> myscript.py` behave like `python myscript.py`?
And: What's the difference of what happens in the two cases? Why is calling the script directly being executed by a separate python process, and not as a subprocess within the shell?
(That assumption of what's happening is probably wrong in concept and in wording, but i think that's what is happening.)

Why i bother:
In PowerShell (or CMD), i can run `PS>myscript.py` from anywhere, because i added it's path to the PATH environment variable.
Problem is, it will open a new window, that closes after execution. So i can't see the script output afterwards.

My first idea, calling `python myscript.py` needs more typing and more importantly, works only if myscript.py is a full path.
A workaround to that would be to add the script to Python's modules path PYTHONPATH and then call it as a module: `python -m myscript`, but that's still more typing and more to remember, so still a workaround.

Comment: I'm pretty sure calling your script within python with `subprocess.Popen` will do what you want. Also, adding `& cmd` or `& pause` to the end of your command line should keep the second window open.

Comment: @OneMadGypsy, i can't follow any of your advice. Can you give full commandline examples?
I got errors for `> esptool.py & cmd` and `> python subprocess.Popen esptool.py`
Anyways, that would also still be a workaround. I am ideally lLookning for a way to make `> myscript.py` behave like `python myscript.py`